# Magento 2 - lost file

Tags: magento2, forms

I sadly was deleting a core file and can't get it back.
It is this one:

> /magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Shipping/Method/Form.php

Can someone post it?
Thanks!:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the file from git. This is from 2.2 branch:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Shipping/Method/Form.php

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is run **composer update**

Answer (score 1):

When I accidentaly delete a file, I go to my CPanel and .trash on root folder. Have you tried?